# Mongoose nested schema only save value of document without including the nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im trying to add a key to specify if mobile number and email address has been verified, but when I save it to the database, there is no verified but only the value of email address and mobile number, how do i add the verified object into it? or is there better method to tell whether mobile number and email has been verified?

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({   username:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: [true,'Sorry username is taken please try another']   },
    phone: {
    verified:{
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    number:{
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: [true,'Mobile already registered']
    },
    type: Array
    },   
    email: {
    verified:{
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    address:{
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: [true,'Email already registered']
    },
    type: Array   },
    dateCreated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()   } }) 
    module.exports = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check from client side for some verification then you can post data to server and either use `ObjectId` or `email` as unique/primary key to change `verify` key's value using [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/)

ex.

```js
const user = await User.updateOne({ _id: userObjId }, { verified: true })
```

or you can use email from payload data if that's enough to fulfill your request

```js
const user = await User.updateOne({ email: userEmail }, { verified: true })
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your information but my question is that I cannot save a nested object in mobile number or email to tell if this user have verified his mobile number and email or not

Comment: your schema itself says that `number` is a String you cannot store Object in that key or else you can modify your schema

Comment: Yes number is a string inside of phone, which can be used as phone.number in my expectation, same as the verified can be use as phone.verified

Comment: so there must be some process right to verify. Suppose there's a OTP so you must be having the otp number in your database for that document right. Then you can do like `.updateOne({ $and: [{ number: userNumber }, { otp: otpNumber }] }, { verified: true })`